# How to start and stop a process in a Jest automated test?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, child-process

I am trying to write a jest automated test that starts my node server, attempts to connect to it, and then stops the node server.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

jest.setTimeout(100000);

test('starting the root-config opens a webserver on port 9000', async () => {
  // given we have started the root-config project
  var serverProcess = require('child_process').spawn('npm run start')

  // when we request http://localhost:9000/
  var response;
  var done = false;
  while(!done) {
    try {
      response = await fetch("http://localhost:9000");
      done = true;
    } catch(e) {
    }
  }

  // terminate the server process when we're done getting a response
  serverProcess.kill('SIGKILL');

  // then we will get a 200 response
  expect(response.status).toBe(200);
});
```

This will reliably start the server, but it rarely manages to stop the server and Jest refuses to terminate.

Comment: Not sure if you need to start and stop localhost for **one** test only or if it's for every test. If it's the latter case, perhaps having a `jest-puppeteer.config.js` as described in [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-end-to-end-testing-jest-puppeteer) would help.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Problem

The reason your library doesn't terminate is likely because your `npm run start` child process is spawning other processes, and these ones are not terminated before Jest closes.

There are a few ways around this, e.g. finding a way to terminate those processes, or use libraries that are dedicated to setting up and tearing down a development server. I'll be providing both a synchronous and an asynchronous solution, although I recommend going with the asynchronous version if your situation allows for it as async is more the nature of NodeJS.

## 2. Solution

### 2.1. Synchronous

I wrote [kill-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-sync) recently, which can kill processes recursively (i.e. terminate all processes in the tree):

- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-sync
- github: https://github.com/nktnet1/kill-sync

From your code, rather than:

```js
const serverProcess = require('child_process').spawn('npm run start');

// Do stuff

serverProcess.kill('SIGKILL');
```

You can modify it to:

```
import killSync from 'kill-sync';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

const serverProcess = spawn('npm run start');

// Do stuff

// specify "true" for recursive 'SIGKILL' to children + grandchildren
killSync(serverProcess.pid, 'SIGKILL', true);
```

### 2.2. Asynchronous

There is also the equivalent [tree-kill](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-tree-kill) package if you wish to use asynchronous code.

From its documentation, you can use it as follows:

```js
import kill from 'tree-kill';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

// Do stuff

const serverProcess = spawn('npm run start');
kill(serverProcess.pid, 'SIGKILL', function(err) {
    // Do things
});
```

## 3. Using Dedicated Dev-server Libraries

### 3.1. Synchronous

I also wrote a library called sync-dev-server that may be able to help with this:

- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-dev-server
- github: https://github.com/nktnet1/sync-dev-server

A basic example as of version 1.0.1 is:

```js
// const { startServer, stopServer } = require('sync-dev-server');
import { startServer, stopServer } from 'sync-dev-server';

const options = {
  // Note: all fields below are optional with set defaults
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 9000,
  timeout: 10000,
  debug: true,
  signal: 'SIGKILL',
  usedPortAction: 'ignore', // alternatives are 'kill' and 'error'
  env: {
    someKey: "someValue"
  },
}

const server = startServer('npm start', options);

// Do stuff

stopServer(server, 'SIGKILL');
```

### 3.2. Asynchronous

As alluded to by GlyphCat's comment to your question, Jest puppeteer can come in handy. In particular, there is an independent subpackage called [jest-dev-server](https://github.com/argos-ci/jest-puppeteer/tree/main/packages/jest-dev-server#readme) for this purpose.

The documentation shows numerous examples which I recommend taking a look at. For a simple use case, it could look like:

```js
import { setup, teardown } from 'jest-dev-server';

const server = await setup({
  command: 'npm start',
  launchTimeout: 5000,
  port: 3000
});

// Do stuff

teardown(server);
```

Note that [jest-dev-server](https://github.com/argos-ci/jest-puppeteer/tree/main/packages/jest-dev-server#readme) actually uses [tree-kill](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-tree-kill) under the hood, similar to how [sync-dev-server](https://github.com/nktnet1/sync-dev-server) leverages [kill-sync](https://github.com/nktnet1/kill-sync).

---

I also recommend that you gracefully handle the appropriate signal in your server. For example, inside a `server.js`, you could have something like:

```js
/**
 * Handle Ctrl+C gracefully
 */
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Shutting down server gracefully.');

    // 99% of the time not necessary, but I've encountered instances
    // where this was needed (I haven't looked into the reason why):
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps :).

Comment: please disclose affiliation when promoting your products

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois,
Thank you for your review. I'm not too sure how I can do this :(. Could you help explain what disclosing affiliation means? The libraries I wrote are self-owned, independent and open-source, and not associated with any institution.
I did add an npm tag to help some students find server-related synchronous packages more easily, but it's not associated with any institutions (I don't receive any benefits, or at least I think I don't - unless I misunderstood?). It's a hobby side-project. Could you please let me know how I can edit my post to satisfy the guidelines. Thank you!!